# Kinematic and dynamic equations of Robot

Tags: ros, kinematics, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone,
I was using innok_heros model for my learning of ROS. I wish if I could have a resource explaining the kinematic equation of the differential drive and other dynamic performance related equations for this robot or any other differential drive robot simulated using ROS.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244540/kinematic-and-dynamic-equations-of-robot/) by [FAIZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/28020/faiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2016-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, just search for differential drive info.

Example: (the video is OK, but, it is kind of slow)

https://chess.eecs.berkeley.edu/eecs149/documentation/differentialDrive.pdf

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aE7RQNhwnPQ

http://rossum.sourceforge.net/papers/DiffSteer/DiffSteer.html

**If you are done with the theory**, then, look at this package and to some of the projects that are using it: http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller

There is a package that seems to be what you are asking for: http://wiki.ros.org/differential_drive

**For learning the core of wheeled mobile robots I recommend you to read chapter 3 of this book:**
http://www.robotee.com/EBooks/Introduction_to_Autonomous_Mobile_Robots.pdf

**BE AWARE**: That Innok Robotics has actually two types of mobile robots (http://wiki.ros.org/Robots/Innok-Heros), one is differential (Innok Heros 223) and the other one is an over-constrained mobile robot (Innok Heros 444) that is used mostly for outdoor purposes and "behaves" like a tank in terms of its way of turning (look at: [http://www-personal.umich.edu/~johannb/Papers/paper95.pdf](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ejohannb/Papers/paper95.pdf)).

---

Originally posted by [pablocesar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20992/pablocesar/) with karma: 252 on 2016-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FAIZ](https://answers.ros.org/users/28020/faiz/) on 2016-09-27**:
Thank you very much for the reply. Since I am new to the ROS environment, I would like to know in what files are the equations for kinetics (suppose for differential drive) are written.